# How to Force an Exception Externally

Tags: c#, exception

I don't know if this is possible, but we have an app that has tons of branding issues, where dialogs and error messages are showing the old name of our product that has now changed.  These boxes are all over the place, many being called from the catch blocks in various windows.  In order to test that everything is working as intended, I was hoping I could create some kind of external tool that could throw an exception within my program, and allow QA to use it.

I can't really make changes to the actual code (especially code that forces exceptions), but I was thinking maybe I make a side program that just allocates all the memory for something silly then the next click on my real app would throw an out of memory exception.  Does this seem plausible?  Is there an easier way to achieve something like this?

Comment: Would that make handling the exception (which might be something that is tested) difficult/impossible with no memory left?

Comment: What kind of error handing you got?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Surely there's a finite limit to the number of dialog boxes which include branding? Search the codebase for every place you launch a dialog and make the corrections.

You could automate the testing by setting up [sikuli](http://sikuli.org/) to capture screen-shots in all your expected failure modes and then search those screenshots (using sikuli's search mechanism) for the branding you're worried about.

Writing a RAM-fill application is fairly trivial if you're certain it's a memory allocation issue that will trigger all these dialogs. Just allocate blocks of ever-decreasing sizes until you run out of memory then use Sikuli to click the button and capture the result. You may well find that if memory allocation is the issue and you're running that close to the wind that your testing fails. If you have serious memory leaks like that you should be fixing them not handing it over to your poor QA team!

Comment: The problem is I have to document every place I change it and have a way for QA to check my work.  Doing a search I found 109 instances, and many of them are in places that would be very difficult to cause the message box to appear as a user (because it is in a try / catch ).  Would be very nice if I could just say, go to this window, push the 'THROW EXCEPTION' button, check message box.

Comment: Sounds like showing them the search for the 109 places and showing your modifications to update those places may be the most pragmatic solution then. If there's nothing in place already to prove that there's any issues and they haven't got any tests which show any problems, then how do you expect to test your fixes?

Comment: I think fundamentally you're going to have to add some code in there (command line option to force exceptions perhaps) to force the errors if they're as obscure as you say they are. Ordinarily, I would use unit tests to provoke these kinds of issues. Make one unit test per dialog which exercises the current problem and show screen shots before. Then fix the issues and run the tests again. Show that output to QA and you're golden!